# How to stop PHP echoing a "1" after being called from "include" within a HTML file?

Tags: php, html, include, output

I'm trying to call my navigation bar by using the following within my HTML code:

```
<?= include 'subfolder/topbar.php'; ?>
```

However, because the script is successfully running, it's echoing a "1" on completion, before my page continues rendering more HTML.
This is then screwing up the spacing within my page.
I've tried to read up on this (and looked at similar threads) but can't find a working resolution.

How do I include the contents of the PHP file without it echoing "1" on completion?

I've also tried putting the include in a variable, but it still outputs the "1":

```
$myX = (include 'subfolder/topbar.php');
```

I've also tried using:

```
include 'subfolder/topbar.php';
return ob_get_clean();
```

But this just halts the output altogether (so the rest of the page doesn't render), much like using the "exit" command.

Comment: use `<?php` tag instead of `<?=` (echo tag) (see all [php tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php))

Comment: `<?=` indicates that PHP should echo the result of the include (success= 1)..... just use `<?php` instead

Comment: Doh, that did it.  Thanks.  I mistakenly thought the <?= was an abbreviated version of the same thing.  After hours of messing I actually tried this seconds before reading your replies.  Typical.

Comment: @BSUK Close. <? is an abbreviated version of <?php.  I am sure you know that, but I just wanted to put it out there! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way should be

```
<? include 'subfolder/topbar.php'; ?>
```

or

```
<?php include 'subfolder/topbar.php'; ?>
```

Your code

```
<?= include 'subfolder/topbar.php'; ?>
```

is like saying

```
<? echo include 'subfolder/topbar.php'; ?>
```